# Web part with Persona stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, spfx-tooling

I have a SPfx web part that uses the Persona component. That component just started failing on SharePoint Online in the last day or two. It still works in my localhost workbench, but fails on SharePoint Online. Removing the persona component fixes the error.

I only get the minified error in the console. https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321

Comment: Which version of react and persona component library are you using? Are those compatible?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.12.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "7.156.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0"
  },

Comment: This is code that has been working for over a year. I assume SharePoint online changed a version of something over the past two days, but I can't find any announcements.

Comment: I changed office-ui-fabric-react from 7.156.0 to 6.214.1 (the version referenced at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components#appendix-upgrading-office-ui-fabric-react-versions. Did not resolve the issue.

Comment: SPFx 1.12.1 supports react v16.9.0.

Comment: @GaneshSanap: I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment. Are you confirming it should work?

Comment: Yes, glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by using the Persona component from "office-ui-fabric-react" instead of "@microsoft/office-ui-fabric-react-bundle".

Previous code:

```
import {
    Persona,
    IPersonaStyles,
    PersonaSize,
    IPersonaProps,
    PersonaInitialsColor,
} from "@microsoft/office-ui-fabric-react-bundle";
```

Updated code:

```
import {
    Persona,
    IPersonaStyles,
    PersonaSize,
    IPersonaProps,
    PersonaInitialsColor,
} from "office-ui-fabric-react";
```

For whatever reason, the bundle does not work on SharePoint Online.